# When sending message getting Exception: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I use Spring Boot version:

[image]

RabbitMQ config:

[image]

error detail:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:69)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.access$200(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:723)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:676)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1600(CachingConnectionFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1430)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2101)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2068)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1068)
    at com.yafex.system.rabbitmq.amqp.RabbitSender.sendMsbByObj(RabbitSender.java:76)
    at com.yafex.system.service.impl.elasticsearch.SPUEventMessageHandler.executeEventMessage(SPUEventMessageHandler.java:60)
    at com.yafex.system.service.impl.elasticsearch.SPUEventMessageHandler.receiveEventMessage(SPUEventMessageHandler.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:148)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:133)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:133)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:182)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:555)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.createChannel(AutorecoveringConnection.java:165)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:58)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=530, reply-text=NOT_ALLOWED - number of channels opened for user 'admin' has reached the maximum allowed user limit of (120000), class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:293)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

I use `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()` send message, and I find this error lead to consumers disappear.